# What is the best way to convert adc values

Tags: type-conversion

I need to convert my ADC result value from an hexadecimal value to a float value and a percentage.

For example I've a 12bit resolution stored into a uint16_t(becouse I've possibility to change resolution). So VREF should be 0x0FFF and GND 0x0000.

Now, I need to convert this values into volts and percentage.

I wanted to do this:

```
float volt, perc, vref;
vref = 3.3;
uint16_t adc_value = ADC_RESULT;

volt = (vref/0x0FFF)*adc_value;

perc = adc_value/(0x0FFF/100);
```

Since I'm performing this operation in a MCU, I wanted to make it more efficent. How do you advice me to do and which type of variable should I use(or made conversions)?